# Create my own action in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there a way to create my own action?

For example when i use scaffold, in the controller it creates "index", "show", "edit" , "new", "create", "update" and "destroy" actions.

I want to add another action.

I have read that i need to add some code on routes file...

Can anyone help me?

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can generate your own actions in a controller simply by defining a method:

```
def action
  # do something here
end
```

You'll need to make sure you have a route setup in config/routes.rb, too.

For more information, I'd suggest reading the guide at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html, specifically http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#generating-a-controller. You'll find that although scaffolds can be useful initially, you have to write your own controller files / action methods as soon as your application gets more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can  just define the action routing in your routes and way you go

Hope this help

Comment: To me, this reads like: **Q** How do I create my own action? **A** Just define your own action. Without any details, links, documentation, etc. it's just saying "yes, you can do that."